# f# : program to calculate difference between dates

Tags: f#

I wrote a part of the program that would calculate the difference between two dates, but I can't add the control of leap years ( ((year % 4 = 0) && ((year % 100 <> 0) || (year % 400 = 0))) ). For example: if my input is 01 01 2001 and 01 01 2005 I get in output 1460, but the year 2004 is a leap year so my output should be 1461.
This is my program:

```
let rec month_length (month : int) (year : int) : int =
    match month with
    | 0 -> failwith "Wrong month"
    | _ when month > 12 -> failwith "Wrong month'"
    | 1 -> 31
    | 2 -> month_length (month - 1) year + 28
    | 4 | 6 | 9 | 11 -> 30 + month_length (month - 1) year 
    | n -> 31 + month_length (n - 1) year 

let data_to_day (day : int) (month : int) (year : int) : int =
    if month = 1 then day
    else day + month_length (month - 1) year

let data_difference (day1 : int) (month1 : int) (year1 : int) (day2 : int) (month2 : int) (year2 : int) : int =
    let dy = year1 - year2
    data_to_day day1 month1 year1 - data_to_day day2 month2 year2 + (dy * 365)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason for not using DateTime type ?

Comment: you can add your *control* as a **guard** with `| ... when ((year % 4 = 0) && ...) -> ...`

Comment: I can't use libraries

Comment: Compensate for the missing leap year days over the time range on (dy * 365).

Comment: @Simone System.DateTime is already part of the "mscorlib.dll" and is not an extra library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by *Functional_S* in above comment, code is not compensating leap year days.

With assumption of not using any libraries below is modified code. Its not elegant solution but it is one way to handle leap year / month days.

```
let feb_month_days year =
    if ((year % 4 = 0) && ((year % 100 <> 0) || (year % 400 = 0))) then 29
    else 28

let year_days year =
    if ((year % 4 = 0) && ((year % 100 <> 0) || (year % 400 = 0))) then 366
    else 365

let rec month_length (month : int) (year : int) : int =
    match month with
    | 0 -> failwith "Wrong month"
    | _ when month > 12 -> failwith "Wrong month'"
    | 1 -> 31
    | 2 -> month_length (month - 1) year + (feb_month_days year)
    | 4 | 6 | 9 | 11 -> 30 + month_length (month - 1) year 
    | n -> 31 + month_length (n - 1) year 

let data_to_day (day : int) (month : int) (year : int) : int =
    if month = 1 then
        day
    else
        day + month_length (month - 1) year

let data_difference (day1 : int) (month1 : int) (year1 : int) (day2 : int) (month2 : int) (year2 : int) : int =
    let dy = year1 - year2
    let range_year_1 = year1 - 1
    let range_year_2 = year2 + 1
    let year2_days = (year_days year2) - (data_to_day day2 month2 year2)
    let year1_days = data_to_day day1 month1 year1
    let between_year_days = seq {for y in range_year_2..range_year_1 do yield year_days y} |> Seq.sum
    year2_days + year1_days + between_year_days

printfn "%A" (data_difference 01 01 2005 01 01 2001) // gives back 1461
```

*Its almost same as above code with addition on 'feb_month_days' and 'year_days' functions*

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone!